# Jenkins declarative pipeline. Conditional statement in post block

Tags: if-statement, jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Have a Jenkins pipeline. Need/want to send emails when build succeeds. Email about all branches to *maillist-1* and filter builds of master branch to *maillist-master*.
I tried using `if` and `when` statements-steps but both of them fail in post block.

```
pipeline {
  agent ...
  stages {...}
  post{
    success{
      archiveArtifacts: ...
      if( env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' ){
        emailext( to: 'maillist-master@domain.com'
                , replyTo: 'maillist-master@domain.com'
                , subject: 'Jenkins. Build succeeded :^) '
                , body: params.EmailBody
                , attachmentsPattern: '**/App*.tar.gz'
        )
      }
      emailext( to: 'maillist-1@domain.com'
                , replyTo: 'maillist-1@domain.com'
                , subject: 'Jenkins. Build succeeded :^) '
                , body: params.EmailBody
                , attachmentsPattern: '**/App*.tar.gz'
        )
      }
    }

}
```

How wanted behavior could be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's true you currently can't use `when` in the global post block. `When` must be used inside a stage directive.

It's a logical choice to use `if else`, but you'll need a scripted block inside the declarative pipeline to make this work:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "master", description: 'Which branch?', name: 'BRANCH_NAME')
    }

    stages {
        stage('test'){
            steps {
                echo "my branch is " + params.BRANCH_NAME
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        success{
            script {
                if( params.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' ){
                    echo "mail list master"
                }
                else {
                    echo "mail list others"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output when parameter is master:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] echo
my branch is master
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
mail list master
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

output when parameter is 'test':

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] echo
my branch is test
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
mail list others
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Or to make it even more clean you can call the script as a function:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "master", description: 'Which branch?', name: 'BRANCH_NAME')
    }

    stages {
        stage('test'){
            steps {
                echo "my branch is " + params.BRANCH_NAME
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        success{
            getMailList(params.BRANCH_NAME)
        }
    }
}

def getMailList(String branch){
    if( branch == 'master' ){
        echo "mail list master"
    }
    else {
        echo "mail list others"
    }
}
```

Comment: what about if it is outside of the `script` block?