# Declarative pipeline when condition in post

Tags: jenkins

As far as declarative pipelines go in Jenkins, I'm having trouble with the *when* keyword.

I keep getting the error `No such DSL method 'when' found among steps`.  I'm sort of new to Jenkins 2 declarative pipelines and don't think I am mixing up scripted pipelines with declarative ones.

The goal of this pipeline is to run `mvn deploy` after a successful Sonar run and send out mail notifications of a failure or success.  I only want the artifacts to be deployed when on master or a release branch.

The part I'm having difficulties with is in the *post* section.  The **Notifications** stage is working great.  Note that I got this to work without the *when* clause, but really need it or an equivalent.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
    maven 'M3'
    jdk 'JDK8'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Notifications') {
      steps {
        sh 'mkdir tmpPom'
        sh 'mv pom.xml tmpPom/pom.xml'
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'origin/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://repository.git']]])
        sh 'mvn clean test'
        sh 'rm pom.xml'
        sh 'mv tmpPom/pom.xml ../pom.xml'
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    success {
      script {
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
      }
      when { 
        branch 'master|release/*' 
      }
      steps {
        sh 'mvn deploy'
      }     
      sendNotification(recipients,
        null,             
        'https://link.to.sonar',
        currentBuild.result,
      )
    }
    failure {
      script {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
      }    
      sendNotification(recipients,
        null,             
        'https://link.to.sonar',
        currentBuild.result
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's true you currently can't use when in the global post block. 'When' must be used inside a stage directive.
It's a logical choice to use if else, but you'll need a scripted block inside the declarative pipeline to make this work: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559882/jenkins-declarative-pipeline-conditional-statement-in-post-block/49565066#49565066

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) of declarative pipelines, it's mentioned that you can't use `when` in the `post` block. `when` is allowed only inside a stage directive.
So what you can do is test the conditions using an `if` in a `script`:

```
post {
success {
  script {
    if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master')
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
  }
 }
// failure block
}
```

Comment: Might need to use `${env.BRANCH_NAME}` instead of `${GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH}`.

Comment: If you're using a windows box you need speech marks around it `"${env.BRANCH_NAME}"`

Comment: For me this just works when writing the variable without the `${}`. Is this a recent change in Jenkins behavior?

Comment: this should be edited to use `if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master')`

Answer (score 21):

Using a GitHub Repository and the [Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) I have something along these lines:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh '''
          make
        '''
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    always {
      sh '''
        make clean
      '''
    }
    success {
      script {
        if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
          emailext (
            to: 'engineers@green-planet.com',
            subject: "${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER} master is fine",
            body: "The master build is happy.\n\nConsole: ${env.BUILD_URL}.\n\n",
            attachLog: true,
          )
        } else if (env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith('PR')) {
          // also send email to tell people their PR status
        } else {
          // this is some other branch
        } 
      }
    }     
  }
}
```

And that way, notifications can be sent based on the type of branch being built. See the [pipeline model definition](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-model-definition/) and also the global variable reference available on your server at http://your-jenkins-ip:8080/pipeline-syntax/globals#env for details.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue with `post`. Worked around it by annotating the variable with `@groovy.transform.Field`. This was based on info I found in the Jenkins docs for [defining global variables](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables).

e.g.

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Validate") {
            parallel {
                stage("Ubuntu") {
                    agent {
                        label "TEST_MACHINE"
                    }
                    steps {{
                        sh "run tests command"
                        recordFailures('Ubuntu', 'test-results.xml')
                        junit 'test-results.xml'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        unsuccessful { 
            notify()
        }
    }
}

// Make testFailures global so it can be accessed from a 'post' step
@groovy.transform.Field
def testFailures = [:]

def recordFailures(key, resultsFile) {
    def failures = ... parse test-results.xml script for failures ...
    if (failures) {
        testFailures[key] = failures
    }
}

def notify() {
    if (testFailures) {
        ... do something here ...
    }
}
```