# Jenkinsfile declarative syntax for conditional post-build step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile for a multibranch pipeline like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        // ...
    }
    post { 
        failure { 
            mail to: 'team@example.com',
                 subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
                 body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to only send email for failures on the master branch.  Is there a way to make the mail step conditional?  Based on the documentation a `when` directive may only be used inside a `stage`.

- https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when
- https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

like you've noted **when** only works inside a **stage**.  And only valid **step**s can be used inside the **post** *conditions*.
You can still use *scripted syntax* inside of a **script** block, and **script** blocks are a valid **step**.  So you should be able to use **if** inside a **script** block to get the desired behavior.

```
...
  post {
    failure {
      script {
        if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
          ... # your code here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

see [JENKINS-52689](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52689)

Comment: Previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798549/declarative-pipeline-when-condition-in-post)

Comment: I guess that means you can't use declarative syntax for the conditional steps though, which is too bad.