# How to have separate mail body in jenkins for code review and Push

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am using gerrit code-review plugin in jenkins to run a job and send a mail upon completion.
I want to have different mail body when code is in review and when it is pushed to repo.

```
stages {
      stage('stage1') {
............
   }
     stage('stage2') {
..........
}
   post {
      success {
      mail to:"xyz@abc.com",
      subject:"SUCCESS",
      body: "Jenkins Review passed "
      }
      failure {
      mail to:"xyz@abc.com",
      subject:"FAILED",
      body: "Jenkins Review failed"
      }
}
```

This sends mail that review is passed or failed. I want to have 2 more templates that sends mail if push is done to repo with message push to repo success or fail.
Is it possible to do that?
One thing I noticed is that environment variable CHANGE_ID will be null when the code is pushed to repo. Is it possible to have if else statement inside post section to have different mail templates?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the if-else statement inside a script block that you can put inside a post block.

You have to do so because the when directive can be used only inside a stage block.

For more info view at this question: [Declarative pipeline when condition in post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798549/declarative-pipeline-when-condition-in-post)